# Local RTX 2080 is 3x faster than V100 on GCP?

Tags: machine-learning, training, google-cloud

I have a gaming rig with an i9 CPU, 32GB RAM and RTX 2080, and I have a GCP VM with 4 vCPU, 52 GB RAM and V100.

I try to train the same dataset using the same toolchain on both machines and these are my ETA's:

GCP VM: 16 days
Gaming rig: 5 days

How can a single $600 GPU outperform a 10k GPU?

What's going on here?

And what should I even expect?

Comment: The V100 should be about 40% faster in row single-precision FLOPS. Are you sure you're not bottlenecked on CPU? your i9 is probably much more powerful. Cloud virtualization can take a little performance off too. Is the data by any chance being read off cloud storage vs local storage in your PC? that would be much slower. I'd look at GPU utilization in the cloud to check whether it's underutilized, which would be a sign of one of those probably.

Comment: Good points. My data is present on an SSD inside the VM.